# MRTK2 Bounds Control Constraint Manager for Move Axis constraint not working in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

In a hololens2 device I want for the user to be able to point and touch a bounding box but not scale/translate/rotate it. I'm working on Unity 2022.1.24 with MRTK 2.8.3.0

I add a Bounds Control component to the object that holds the following components: a collider and the Constrain Manager component that has a RotationAxisContraint for all=XYZ. I've also constrained scale to 1. However picking the bounding box from the corners allows the user to move the bounding box. How can I stop this translation of bounding box from happening?

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the Unity versions officially supported by Microsoft are Unity 2020.3 LTS and Unity 2021.3 LTS. Please refer to [Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version) to select the appropriate Unity version for development.

For your question, to clarify, **MoveAxisConstraint** only works on the behavior of the **Translation Handle**. From your screenshot, you didn't enable **Translation Handle**. If you want to try it, you can check **Show Handle For X/Y/Z** in **BoundsControl/Visuals/TranslationHandlesConfiguration**, and then you can see these **Translation Handles** in the center of each face of the bounding box.

For **MinMaxScaleConstraint** and **Scale Handle**, when the scale of the object has reached the maximum/minimum, the object will move in the direction of dragging, which is by design. If you don't need **Rotate/Scale/Translate**, then you only need to uncheck **Show Handle For X/Y/Z** or **Show Scale Handles** in the corresponding **Configuration** of **BoundsControl/Visuals**.